# Как настроить сеть, чтобы все устройства локалки могли получить доступ к контейнеру?

Tags: docker, сеть, docker-compose

Есть контейнер с сайтом на `django`. С хоста я вижу и могу получить доступ к сайту, но с телефона/ноута не удается это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить это?

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.0"

services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DJANGO_NAME: django_name
      MYSQL_DJANGO_PASSWORD: django-password
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    networks:
      - my_network

  susu_sport_norms:
    container_name: susu
    image: susu
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    name: django
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

Comment: Команда `ports: '8000:8000'` означает, что порт 8000 из "внешней сети" (ваша локалка) будет перенаправляться на 8000 порт сети my_network, т.е. оно уже должно быть доступно с другого компьютера в этой же локалке. Может у вас firewall блокирует входяшие подключения

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, да, нашел свою ошибку... спасибо большое)